# Could somebody validate my proof for the limit of $a^{x_n}$ when $x_n \to c$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation, probability-limit-theorems

So,  here is the clear formulation of the problem:  let $(x_n) $ be a convergent sequence of positive numbers,  with $x_n \to c$.  I want to prove that the sequence $(y_n) $,  with $y_n=a^{x_n} $, tends to $a^c$

I will use the proof by contradiction.  Suppose that $y_n \to,  l$ with $l \neq a^c$.

But,  we know that if $y_n \to l$,  then $\ln{y_n} \to \ln l$.  That means that:

$$\lim{\ln{y_n}} =\ln l$$
$$\lim{\ln{a^{x_n}} } =\ln l$$
$$\lim{(x_n\ln{a}) } =\ln l$$
$$\ln{a}(\lim{x_n}) =\ln l$$
$$c\ln{a} =\ln l$$
$$\ln{a^c} =\ln l$$

And now,  from the injectivity of logarithm function it follows that $l=a^c$, which is a contradiction.  Hence,  Q. E. D.

Please,  can you tell me if my proof is a correct one?

Comment: In the step where you "push" the limit under the logarithm, you implicitly invoke continuity of logarithm. The proof is ok, though this approach is a bit more complicated than using continuity directly to conclude that $\ln a^{x_n}\to\ln a^c$.

Comment: Well,  in fact,  I don't have the concept of continuity very clear in mind,  I haven't studied it yet. Although,  it seems that here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800534/could-somebody-validate-my-proof-regarding-the-limit-of-lnx-n-when-x-n-t/800555?noredirect=1#800555 I proved the continuity of the ln function.  How would a shorter proof look?  Can yoy show me,  please?

Comment: The setup of your proof is invalid. You would need to prove that $y_n$ converges at all. $y_n \not \to a^c$ means $y_n \to l \neq a^c$ *or* $y_n$ diverges.

Comment: So I need to erase the part where I state that I use proof by contradiction, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct provided you're allowed to assume that $\lim (\ln y_n) = \ln (\lim y_n)$.

Your proof structure could be simplified, though: you gave a self-contained proof that $l=a^c$, but surrounded it unnecessarily with 'suppose $l \ne a^c$' and 'contradiction'. If you just didn't assume the result was false (and therefore never reached a contradiction) then you'd still have a proof.

Comment: Wait,  that's right.  Yes,  if l=a^c,  then that's it,  because the limit of a sequence is unique..